# How to eliminate all borders from chartjs2 stacked chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have created a stacked horizontal bar chart that is made up of x number of portions of the day, and there may be y things going on during each portion. If nothing is going on then I want white, if something is happening, then blue (it'll be a '1' in the data and hence pull out Color at index 1), eventually I will change the colors dynamically as well. To create this I am stacking each portion of the day on top of the previous one and coloring it appropriately. The problem is that there is a visible border that 'bleeds' down from the latest portion of the day when something is happening.

I have tried setting borderWidth to 0, I have also tried setting the borderColor to white. Neither made any difference. I then set the borderColor to black and 0.25 width thinking I'd just 'paint over' the cracks. This works to an extent, but the border thickens as you get further towards the 0 points of the axis, reflecting the increasing number of borders that are overlying each other. The pictures below show the bleeding border with a black borderColor and either 0(which still shows the blue) or 0.25 (which shows the changing weight) borderWidth

https://ibb.co/Mc5dZ86

https://ibb.co/TPKGtFJ

```
const data = this.props.ChartData;


    var datasets = []

        const Colors = ["white", "#1B79EC", "#fc407e",]

        for (let i=1; i<data[1].length; i++)
        {datasets.push(

            {   label: data[0],
                data: [data[1][i][0]],
                backgroundColor: [Colors[data[1][i-1][1]]],
                borderColor: ['black'],
                borderWidth: 0} )
    }


    return (

                    <Chart data={
                        {
                            labels: [data[0]],
                            datasets: datasets,

                        }}

                           options={{
                               responsive: true,
                               maintainAspectRatio: false,
                               legend: {
                                   display: false
                               },
                               scales: {
                                   yAxes: [{
                                        stacked:true,
                                        display: true,

                                   }],
                                   xAxes: [{

                                        display:false,
                                       ticks: {
                                           beginAtZero: true,
                                           autoSkip: false,
                                       },
                                   }],
                               }
                           }}
                    />

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for ChartJS here: https://github.com/cprimera/Chart.MultiFloatingBar.js which will give a floating bar chart